# Illustrator: Aligning object to Selection, Key Object or Artboard

Tags: adobe-illustrator

When I have a selection of several objects in Illustrator, and I want to align or distribute them, then *Align to Selection* is often (but not always) selected as default. Clicking on one of the selected objects, automatically turns the mode to *Align to Key Object* which is extremely handy.

Additional features for aligning objects are [pretty well documented here](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/moving-aligning-distributing-objects.html).

**Question:** Is there also an easy way to switch the mode do *Align to Artboard* without using the selector in the Align Panel? I noticed, that sometimes Illustrator does exactly this by default, by I never managed to find out when this happens.

Answer (score 2):

No. Align to Selection, or Align to Artboard stick to whatever was last used in the document. There is no quick-key or quick-toggle between those two items.

Comment: That is unfortunate.

Comment: Completely agree. That is one quick-toggle function that I have been hoping will be added for a long time.